# CMake + JWAsm integration example?

Tags: c++, cmake, jwasm

I'm struggling with integrating JWAsm together with CMake.
I've found an old thread from 2009 which uses CMakeTestASMCompiler to
change the assembler. It defines:

1.) CMakeDetermineASM_JWASMCompiler.cmake

```
SET(ASM_DIALECT "_JWASM")
SET(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS asm)
IF(CMAKE_HOST_WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILE_OBJECT
"<CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER> -nologo -coff <FLAGS> -Fo<OBJECT>
<SOURCE>")
ELSE(CMAKE_HOST_WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILE_OBJECT
"<CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER> -nologo -elf <FLAGS> -Fo<OBJECT>
<SOURCE>")
ENDIF(CMAKE_HOST_WIN32)
INCLUDE(CMakeASMInformation)
SET(ASM_DIALECT)
```

2.) CMakeDetermineASM_JWASMCompiler.cmake

```
SET(ASM_DIALECT "_JWASM")
SET(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER_INIT jwasm)
INCLUDE(CMakeDetermineASMCompiler)
SET(ASM_DIALECT)
```

And it uses like that:

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_JWASM_COMPILER "/usr/sbin/jwasm")
set(ASM_DIALECT "_JWASM")
include(CMakeTestASMCompiler)
set(ASM_DIALECT)
enable_language(ASM_JWASM)
```

My issue: CMake fails locating 1.) and 2.) with the following error message:

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineASM_JWASMCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_JWASM_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: [...]/build/[..]/CMakeFiles/3.13.4/CMakeASM_JWASMCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeASM_JWASMInformation.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeTestASM_JWASMCompiler.cmake
```

Any idea where/how should those .cmake files be installed?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appears the files have to be copied to CMAKE_ROOT/Modules